# Adding a dynamic list of parameters with Html helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'd like to be able to feed in a list of parameter names and values into a Html.Actionlink but the helper doesn't create the parameters as I would like. Any ideas how to do this?

```
public class ParameterNameValue
{
     public string ParameterName { get; set; }
     public string ParameterValue { get; set; }
 }
```

View

```
 @foreach (var action in post.FeedActions)
    {
        var parameters = "";
        foreach (var param in action.Parameters)
        {
           parameters += param.ParameterName + "=" + param.ParameterValue + ",";
         }
         @Html.ActionLink(@action.Label, action.ActionName,
         new { controller = action.Controller, id = action.CommunityId, slug = action.Slug,
         Fromfeed=true,parameters }, new { @class = action.Classes })
   }
```

yields a link like this:
[image]

Whereas I need the parameters part to look like:

```
?FromFeed=true&MatchId=1234&InnerId=5678
```

edit: I got it working by just manually creating the  tag, but no doubt there's a nice way of doing this by creating a custom helper.

```
 <a href="/@action.Slug/@action.CommunityId/@action.Controller-@action.ActionName?Fromfeed=true&@parameters">@action.Label</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to extend the classic ActionLink helper with a prototype similar to this (add a parameter for your specific class) :

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkCustom(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName,  object routeValues, List<ParameterNameValue> yourOtherValues)
```

In the code, check if you got any custom values. If such, add them to the RouteValuesDictionnary. Then use the classic ActionLink helper providing this modified RouteValuesDictionnary.

Note : you can work on the routeValues using this

```
IDictionary<string, object> RouteValues = HtmlHelper.ObjectToDictionary(routeValues);
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks